# R, applying function to each elements in vector

Tags: r

I have numeric vector. I would like to apply some function to each element in this vector: (function is numeric type)
**Example**
`x = c(1.2, 2.21, 2321.213)`
`apply (f, x) = y = (2.2, 3.21, 2322.213)`

Comment: If its some self written function, you can use `sapply`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply a function to each element of a vector in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206461/how-to-apply-a-function-to-each-element-of-a-vector-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply `+(x,1)`  to each element of x, you could write

```
sapply(x, `+`, 1)
# [1]    2.200    3.210 2322.213
```

Comment: Actually `\`+\`(x,1)` is a thing, too.

Comment: Hmmm.. Why not just `x + 1`? Or is that not "in" anymore?

Comment: @DavidArenburg it's not tidy

Comment: Ok, is it possible to use other numeric function ?

Comment: @HaskellFun yes it is. It depends on the function really. Some of the functions are vectorized, some are not. `+` happen to be a vectorized one. You will need to do some Googling/reading the documentation.

Comment: If you have heterogenous objects, say a list with a number and a date, `+` could dispatch differently within the sapply.